# ERD Eclipse plugin that generates hibernate entities

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

i need to use an ERD tool in eclipse, to make ERD diagrams for my database tables
and can generate hibernate classes, please suggest me a good eclipse plugin if there's any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the well known and used ones is http://eclipse-erd.sourceforge.net/

Another good one is http://dbva-for-eclipse-for-windows.visual-paradigm-international-ltd.crystal-product.com/

Note that most of such plugins are NOT free.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to create object class diagram with hibernate annotations.

You can either type the annotation manually in the code and get them immediately updated in your diagram or you can add hibernate stereotypes and got them in the code. It works in both directions.

This is a good alternative to traditional ERD and a lot more powerful approach.